# How to enable the hibernate option?

Tags: 10.04, power-management

I am not getting Hibernate option in ubuntu 10.04. Can anyone say what the problem might be and how to resolve it?

(btw I tried this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq but it didn't work for me)

Comment: Take a look at my blog post on this, it could help http://arecordon.blogspot.com.ar/2013/08/ubuntu-enabling-hibernation.html